# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] error

Tags: javascript, express, web, mongoose

I tried making a program but it seems that I have ran into some problem when i link my route, controller, and schema

I already tried multiple methods to debug and solve this problem but still got the same error message

route.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const eventCatCont = require("../controller/stats");

router.post("/33349800/api/v1/createEventCategory", eventCatCont.createEventCat);
router.get("/33349800/api/v1/list-eventCat", eventCatCont.getAll);
router.delete("/33349800/api/v1/delete-eventCat", eventCatCont.deleteEventCatById);
router.put("/33349800/api/v1/update-eventCat", eventCatCont.updateEventCatById);

module.exports = router;
```

stats.js

```
const StudentSchema = require("../models/student-schema");
const Student2Schema = require("../models/student2-schema");

module.exports = {
    createEventCat: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { name, description, image } = req.body;
            const newCategory = new StudentSchema({
                id: IDGenerator(),
                name,
                description,
                image,
                creationDate:DateGenerator(),
            });

            await newCategory.save();
            res.status(201).json(newCategory);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    },

    getAll: async function (req, res) {
        try {
            const categories = await StudentSchema.find().populate('eventsList');
            res.json(categories);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    },

    deleteEventCatById: async function (req, res) {
        try {
            const eventCatID = req.body.id;
            const deletedEventCat = await StudentSchema.findByIdAndRemove(eventCatID);

            if (!deletedEventCat) {
                res.status(404).json({ error: 'Event Category not found' });
                return;
            }

            res.status(200).json({
                acknowledged: true,
                deletedCount: 1,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    },

    updateEventCatById: async function (req, res) {
        try {
            const eventCatID = req.params.id;
            const updatedCategory = await StudentSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
                eventCatID,
                {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    image: req.body.image,
                    creationDate: DateGenerator(),
                },
                { new: true }
            );

            if (!updatedCategory) {
                res.status(404).json({ error: 'Event Category not found' });
                return;
            }

            res.status(200).json(updatedCategory);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    },
};

function IDGenerator() {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    let result = 'C';
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
        result += characters[randomIndex];
    }
    result += '-';
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        const randomDigit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        result += randomDigit;
    }
    return result;
}
function DateGenerator(){
    function randomNumberGenerator(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    return randomNumberGenerator(1,30) + " - " + randomNumberGenerator(1,12) + " - " + randomNumberGenerator(2017, 2023)
}
```

student-schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const alphanumericPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/;
const eventsCatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validate: {
        validator: function (value) {
            return alphanumericPattern.test(value);
        },
        message: 'Name must contain only alphanumeric characters.',
      },
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    image: String,
    creationDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    eventsList: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Event', // Reference to the Event model
        },
    ],
  });

const EventCat = mongoose.model('EventsCat', eventsCatSchema);

module.exports = EventCat;
```

Can you help me debug this code and possibly share some solution to this problem since I have been stuck with this without any lead on what to do next. I ran into this error code when I try to run routes.js

Comment: verify the path of controller whether its correct or not. const eventCatCont = require("../controller/stats");